# adding width to drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to be able to add width to this drawer because it takes up too much of the screen when open and I want to lessen the width a bit, is this possible and  how would I do this?

here is my scaffold

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("App Name"),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: new Center(
  ),

  drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text('Test123') ,
        accountEmail: Text('test@123.com'),
        currentAccountPicture: Image.network('https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a89c3e38-b6f3-48a0-9f9e-df9a0129fb93/daghh5x-4a77b3ec-fd4f-4d17-9f84-5963a8cb5c03.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E4OWMzZTM4LWI2ZjMtNDhhMC05ZjllLWRmOWEwMTI5ZmI5M1wvZGFnaGg1eC00YTc3YjNlYy1mZDRmLTRkMTctOWY4NC01OTYzYThjYjVjMDMucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.dWTFMrwnbAbj5TtUp9U_vQsohW7MnkRPymzR5wZQoV8'),
        ),

        ListTile(
          title: Text('data'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Wrap the Drawer widget inside a Container widget and pass the width parameter to the Container.

```
drawer: Container(
      width: 50,
      child: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text('Test123'),
              accountEmail: Text('test@123.com'),
              currentAccountPicture: Image.network(
                  'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a89c3e38-b6f3-48a0-9f9e-df9a0129fb93/daghh5x-4a77b3ec-fd4f-4d17-9f84-5963a8cb5c03.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E4OWMzZTM4LWI2ZjMtNDhhMC05ZjllLWRmOWEwMTI5ZmI5M1wvZGFnaGg1eC00YTc3YjNlYy1mZDRmLTRkMTctOWY4NC01OTYzYThjYjVjMDMucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.dWTFMrwnbAbj5TtUp9U_vQsohW7MnkRPymzR5wZQoV8'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is **another example** to give width to the Drawer.

```
return SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75, // 75% of screen will be occupied
  child: Drawer(
    
  ),
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this method once.

```
drawer: Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
child: Drawer()
),
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Before**

[image]

### After

Scaffold `Drawer` with `Container` or `Sizeable` widget

```
Container(
          width: 125,
          child: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                const DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('google.com'),
                  onTap: () {
                    widget._controller!.loadUrl(
                        urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("www.google.com")));

                    // Update the state of the app.
                    // ...
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('yahoo.com'),
                  onTap: () {
                    widget._controller!.loadUrl(
                        urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("www.yahoo.com")));
                    // ...
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

return Scaffold(
drawer: Drawer(
width: ihmParams.menuWidth,
child: leftMenu(
closeMenu: true,
),
),

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msb5y.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).